# Doesn't awk print all lines if it is passed empty arguments

Tags: awk

I thought that `awk` without arguments is equivalent to `awk {print} file`.
But when I do:

```
awk '' file
```

Nothing is printed.

Why?

Comment: Who said `''` was nothing...? :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in your case, `awk` evaluated a false condition, and no associated actions so it does nothing.

`awk` does default action print when a condition is true and no actions are specified,

Try:

```
awk 1 file
```